# How to open documents in html(inside iframe or div) by passing document path

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, html

I have a requirement in my application like,I need to open files(pdf,docx,pptx..)with in html(embedding into div or iframe) by passing document paths(urls) on click of a button.
I have tried opening the documents outside the application and its working,But I am stuck on hw to approach the above problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I had initially tried with jqlite but that doesnt help to open files which are located in local drives.So I tried to open the files with the help of java file process methods.That helps me to open files in their respective applications.But that doesnt help me to open files with in html(embedded in iframe or div)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a iframe inside a div and o0pen the document in that iframe element as follows:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="" id="iframeRight" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">

    </iframe>
</div>
```

In the controller, on click of button you can assign the base64 string of the document to iframe src as follows:

```
document.getElementById("iframeRight").src = base64String;
```

Just ensure that the base64 string has the metadata attached to it like for pdf it must start as:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,
```

PFB a demo program that lets user select the document and displays the same in the iframe. Copy paste in notepad and run  this as html file. Select a doc less than 5 mb in size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file-uploadUC" />
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" id="ifrm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("file-uploadUC").addEventListener("change", rdfile);
function rdfile() {
        extn = '';
        FileContentBase64 = '';
        FileName = '';
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            if (this.files[0].size <= 5347738) {
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FileName = this.files[0].name;
                extn = FileName.split(".").pop();
                FR.onload = function (e) {
                    FileContentBase64 = e.target.result;
                    document.getElementById("ifrm").src = FileContentBase64;
                };
                FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        else {
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u explain the controller part and how base64String works

Comment: getting error message "jquery.min.js:3 Not allowed to load local resource:"

Comment: can u explain how to assign base64 string to src

Comment: demo html code added in answer. copy paste and save as HTML and run.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code,but it not working in IE,in chrome it downloads the file.